# Bulk product import Woocommerce Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, import

I'm trying to use this plugin https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/ to bulk import more than 10000 variable products in CSV in Woocommerce.

In their support, they say to use parent SKU, product SKU and product type columns from CSV.

The problem is that the CSV comes from my customer's supplier not-Woocommerce database, we have :

One product variation for each row,
Variation SKU,
Main SKU,
Sizes for each product variation in their row,
Color for each product variation in their row,

What we don't have: Product type

How can we solve the problem for scheduled mass import?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the product type specified in the CSV file, then you can use the evaluation field section on the import mapping screen to specify the product type and then import. Please note that if you specify the type in the evaluation field, then all the products in the CSV file will be imported with that product type.